# Problems with Replace - pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df

```
df:
  date     shares  symbol  date2
0 20120614  1100   AAT.N   NaN
1 20120615  1100   AAT.N   NaN
2 20120616  1100   AAT.N   NaN
3 20120617  1100   AAT.N   NaN
4 20030405  800    ABT.N   NaN
5 20030406  800    ABT.N   NaN
6 20030407  800    ABT.N   NaN
...

#This is what I want:
df:
  date     shares  symbol  date2
0 20120614  1100   AAT.N   20120615
1 20120615  1100   AAT.N   20120616
2 20120616  1100   AAT.N   20120617
3 20120617  1100   AAT.N   NaN
4 20030405  800    ABT.N   20030406
5 20030406  800    ABT.N   20030407
6 20030407  800    ABT.N   NaN
...
```

I want to replace df.ix[0]['date2'] with df.ix[1]['date2'] for each symbol -- the symbol changes through the dataframe so I can't just apply this through the whole dataframe.

I was going to loop through and if the symbol for i and i+1 matched:

```
df.ix[i]['symbol'] == df.ix[i+1]['symbol']
```

I was going to replace the NaN with the date.

I tried:

```
df.ix[i]['date2'] = df.ix[i+1]['date']  ##This failed.
```

I then tried:

```
a = df.ix[i+1]['date']
df.replace({'date2': i}, a)
###This failed as well
```

Any recommendations here on

1)  Best process to accomplish this?

2)  Basic question:  How to replace an NaN (or even another number) in a pandas DF?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And here's a one-line solution that might be the most 'pandonic':

```
In [8]: df['date2'] = df.groupby('symbol').apply(lambda x: x['date'].shift(-1))

In [9]: df
Out[9]:
       date  shares symbol     date2
0  20120614    1100  AAT.N  20120615
1  20120615    1100  AAT.N  20120616
2  20120616    1100  AAT.N  20120617
3  20120617    1100  AAT.N       NaN
4  20030405     800  ABT.N  20030406
5  20030406     800  ABT.N  20030407
6  20030407     800  ABT.N       NaN
```

Comment: And like DSM states, this won't work if you have different groups of the same symbol that you want to keep distinct.

Comment: plus 1 for using .apply() where my solution used a for loop. I always forget about apply.

Comment: You can even omit the lambda function with  ``df.groupby("symbol").date.shift(-1)``.  groupby objects will dispatch to underlying Series/DataFrame methods (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#dispatching-to-instance-methods)

Answer (score 1):

To compare to DSM's boolean solution, here's the quick and painless groupby solution!

```
grouped = df.groupby('symbol')
for _, group in grouped:
    df1['date2'][group.index] = group.shift(-1)['date']
```

Answer (score 0):

I might do something like this:

```
>>> df
       date  shares symbol  date2
0  20120614    1100  AAT.N    NaN
1  20120615    1100  AAT.N    NaN
2  20120616    1100  AAT.N    NaN
3  20120617    1100  AAT.N    NaN
4  20030405     800  ABT.N    NaN
5  20030406     800  ABT.N    NaN
6  20030407     800  ABT.N    NaN
>>> same_symbols = df['symbol'] == df['symbol'].shift(-1)
>>> df['date2'][same_symbols] = df['date'].shift(-1)
>>> df
       date  shares symbol     date2
0  20120614    1100  AAT.N  20120615
1  20120615    1100  AAT.N  20120616
2  20120616    1100  AAT.N  20120617
3  20120617    1100  AAT.N       NaN
4  20030405     800  ABT.N  20030406
5  20030406     800  ABT.N  20030407
6  20030407     800  ABT.N       NaN
```

This finds where the symbols are the same from one row to the next:

```
>>> same_symbols
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
Name: symbol, Dtype: bool
```

and then applies the shifted dates there:

```
>>> df['date'].shift(-1)
0    20120615
1    20120616
2    20120617
3    20030405
4    20030406
5    20030407
6         NaN
Name: date, Dtype: float64
```

This assumes the symbol data is contiguous and already sorted (easy enough to impose if it's not that way already.)

Alternatively you could use `groupby` and then act on each group, reassembling things at the end.